# Swing JTable how to update it? and fill it?

Tags: java, swing, jtable, resultset

Well I have 2 queries 
a) select * from players
b)select * from players where idplayer=10;

Now I would to know what is the form easiest for to fill it first I created my table
JTable mytable = new JTable(10,7); // ok..
// as in java there is not gridview or datagridview do we have to use JTable?
well how do i fill it? have to JButtons one for fill it with all players
and another for fill it with query B. how do i update it?

I repeat I would to know the form easiest.. 
thanks
this is my code

```
public ResultSet buscarfutbolistas() {
    ResultSet datos = null;
    String cadena="select * from futbolistas";
    try {
        Statement stm = conexion.getConnection().createStatement();
        datos = stm.executeQuery(cadena);
    } catch(Exception ex) {
        System.out.println(ex);
    }
    return datos; 
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Table From Database](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/03/12/table-from-database/) might help you.

Answer (score 1):

You have to create a TableModel.
See here for more information and a complete tutorial:

> http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html